# Can't make sequelize model relation working

Tags: sequelize.js

I working on a training project and i have some trouble to make it work. Especially on relations.

I'm trying to make relation between my **Users** model and my **Roles** model but all i have tried here never worked.

Here is my **Users** model :

```
    const Role = require('./roles')

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {

    const User = sequelize.define("user",{
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.UUID,
            defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        firstName: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        password: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        }

    })

    return User
}
```

Here is my **Roles** model :

```
const User = require('./users')

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {

    const Role = sequelize.define("role",{
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.UUID,
            defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        description: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: true
        },

    })

    // here is the error
    Role.hasMany(User)

    return Role
}
```

I think the problem come from the file wheere i initialize sequelize.

Here is the file **index** :

```
const dbConfig = require('../config.js')
const mysql = require('mysql2')
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const { host, dialect, user, password, database } = dbConfig.database

// creation de la connection à mariadb
const connection = mysql.createConnection({ host, user, password, password })

// Creation de la base de donnée
connection.query(`CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS ${database}`,
    (err, resultats) => {
        if(err) throw new Error(`[ERROR] - ${err}`)
    }
)

// Connection de sequelize à mariadb
const sequelize = new Sequelize(database, user, password, {
    host,
    dialect
});

try {
    sequelize.authenticate()
    console.info('[INFO] - Connected to Mariadb database')
}catch(err) {
    console.error(`[ERROR] - Can't connect do database, error : ${err}`)
}

const db = {}
db.sequelize = sequelize
db.models = {}
db.models.User = require('./users')(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes)
db.models.Role = require('./roles')(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes)

module.exports = db
```

And here is my error :

```
.hasMany called with something that's not a subclass of Sequelize.Model
```

I guess i reference the model wrongly but can't figure out why.

I've tried to import and use db.models.User and it didn't work.

Is someone have an idea? What i missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you missunderstood how and where you have to define this relation.
The relations should be established **after** your models were defined in sequelize i.e. after your definitions were actually called.

In your case you call definitions here:

> const db = {}
> db.sequelize = sequelize
> db.models = {}
> db.models.User = require('./users')(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes)
> db.models.Role = require('./roles')(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes)

so actual association code shoud be lower than that.
For example you can establish the relation right after these lines just like that:

```js
db.models.User = require('./users')(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes)  
db.models.Role = require('./roles')(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes)  

//One-to-many relation between User and Role
db.models.User.hasMany(db.models.Role)
db.models.Role.belongsTo(db.models.User)
```